# hide data in active directory to a specific account

Tags: active-directory

We are contemplating using Windows AD as LDAP for an DMZ Ubuntu environment and discovered that a simple LDAP query from a DMZ ubuntu server resulted in a complete listing of all AD objects. (We temporarily opened up LDAP from the DMZ to the internal AD server) I have thought that by using the delegating task that I could limit the account to just be able to read certain OUs, such as Accounts and Groups and nothing else. Doing some research, this doesn't appear to be the case as the List Object option seems a bit complex. I'd just like to limit any attackers reconnaissance as much as possible.

any one else out there had a similar conundrum?

Thanks,
Joe

Answer (score 0):

Is that Ubuntu server on the same domain as the DC it's querying?

If it's getting that data without using an account, then you have some basic recommended securing to do - disable anonymous LDAP binds, anonymous SID/name translation, and anonymous enumeration of SAM accounts.  Make sure anonymous users aren't included in the `Pre-Windows 2000 Compatible Access` group.

If it's authenticated with a domain account, and you're looking to restrict visibility to sensitive objects for that account, you'll need to get creative with the permissions.  By default, the `Authenticated Users` identity, which is applied to all accounts, has some basic object read capabilities against the entire domain.

To restrict that access to "hide" accounts from other, less-privileged accounts, you'll want to remove that access for specific OUs by disabling inheritance on them and building a custom ACL for the OU.

Keep in mind that there can be some very interesting consequences when you do this - bad things happen when a logging in user account can't read the computer account that it's logging into and vice versa, and SID resolution to the hidden objects can cause some interesting failures, especially in third-party software.  **If your organization's security policies demand that you do go down this road, tread lightly, think through your changes, and test thoroughly.**